# Need to have different IIS Rewrite rule on CD and CM while using Sitecore Azure Module

Tags: azure, content-management, content-delivery, url-rewrite

We are using the Sitecore Azure Module to deploy to CD delivery farms.  We want to use an IIS Rewrite Rule to redirect all traffic on CD to SSL - however, we do not want the same rule applied on CM (which is our on-premise server from which we push our site to Azure via the Azure Module).

When using the Azure module, CM and CD share config files.  Is there a way for us to drop a re-write rule into the web.config that will ONLY be applied to CD, and not to CM? Or some kind of alternative equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CM and CD servers are available by different addresses.(e.g.: cms.test.com and www.test.com)

It is possible to filter redirect rule before execution using {HTTP_HOST} variable:

```
<rule name="Force SSL" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="yourCDaddress1" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="yourCDaddress2" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

where yourCDaddress1, yourCDaddress2, etc.  your CD addresses, e.g.: www.test.com, test.com, etc.